# WebStorm doesn't recognize ES6 export default

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm, browserify

I'm probably overthinking this, but can't seem to figure out the difference between the first and second modules below.

The first is accepted, parsed and suggested by WebStorm as "missing import statement" and then it pulls the module. The second however simply says "Element is not exported". As an example, I put a ReactJS component at the end, which does work.

```
// first module - is being recognized as an exported module.
export default {
    foo() {}
};

// second module - "Element is not exported"
const AnObject = {
    foo2() {}
};

export default AnObject;

// ReactJS Example Component - works just as fine
const Component = React.createClass({
    bar() {}
});
export default Component;
```

There is definitely a difference between the `AnObject` and `Component` declaration, though I don't see how that affects the export.

Can anyone explain why I'm experiencing this behaviour with WebStorm?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in WebStorm 2016.2:

[image]

No errors are reported, I can navigate for foo2 definition from its usage, etc.

Comment: I can't upload any images. On hover for AnObject I get "Element is not exported" instead of the "Missing import statement", which I would expect. If I write the import statement myself, I can navigate to the definition and it does get recognized. I did try 2016.2 as well.